# Geocoding function in ArcGIS online

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I need to get the extent (bounding box) from a placename (i.e. United States of America, Virginia, Charlottesville). What is the appropriate function to call in the JS API?

I want to do it programmatically as if I had typed it into the search widget.

The map is made with the JS API:

```
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.12"></script>

map=new Map({ basemap:baseMap, });                          
    activeView=app.mapView=new MapView({                                                                                         
    container:container, map:map                                                                 
    });
```

I can use a REST function like this, but there must be an internal function:

```
 url="http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?f=pjson&SingleLine="+loc;
    $.ajax( { url: url, dataType: 'jsonp' } ).done(function(res) {                      
          extent=res.candidates[0].extent;                                          
    });
```

Comment: Hi, what service are you using? Please edit your question to provide more info that will help us help you.

Comment: ok, I've updated the q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jquery AJAX is not bad, you can achieve the same thing with ESRI API by using the [`esri/tasks/locator`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/locator-amd.html) class and its [`addressToLocations`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/locator-amd.html#locationtoaddress) method

```
require(["esri/tasks/locator"], function(Locator) {

  var locator = new Locator("http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer");

  locator.addressToLocations(loc).then(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
      var extent = res.candidates[0].extent;    
  });
```

Comment: So is there a native function, like findAddressCandidates()?

Comment: sorry I think in your case you should use `addressToLocations` method. If `loc` is an address, the response will contains features with geometry